# Pass array to the derived class in C++

Tags: c++

In Class Dim I created array G and I want to pass it to the derived Class PHYS_FIELD. Instead of output (0..9) it gives (0..0). I realize that it is just a new copy of G but I do not know how to do it correctly.

`arr1.h`:

```
#ifndef ARR1_H
#define ARR1_H

#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

template <class T> class arr1
{

public:

T* data;
size_t size;

arr1(const size_t isize)
{   size=isize;
    data = new T[size];

}

T  & operator ()(size_t const index)
{  return data[index]; }

 };

 #endif /*ARR1_H */
```

`dim.h`:

```
 #ifndef DIM_H
 #define DIM_H

 #include "arr1.h"

 class DIM {
 public:
 DIM();

 protected:

 int N;

 };

 #endif /* DIM_H */
```

`dim.cpp`:

```
 #include "arr1.h"
 #include "dim.h"

 using namespace std;

 DIM :: DIM()

 { 

 N=10;

 arr1<double> G(N);

  for (int i=0; i<N; i++) 
    G(i)=i;     

 };
```

`phys_field.h`:

```
 #ifndef PHYS_FIELD_H
 #define PHYS_FIELD_H

 #include "dim.h"
 #include "arr1.h"

 class PHYS_FIELD : public DIM {

 public:

 PHYS_FIELD();

 arr1<double>  G;

 };

 #endif /* PHYS__FIELD_H */
```

`phys_field.cpp`:

```
 #include "dim.h"
 #include "phys_field.h"
 #include <arr1.h> 

 using namespace std;

 PHYS_FIELD :: PHYS_FIELD(): G(N)   {

 cout<< " from phys_field.cpp "<<endl;
 cout<<N<<endl;    

 for (int i=0; i<N ; i++)
     cout<<i<<" "<<G(i)<<endl; 

 };
```

`main.cpp`:

```
 #include "dim.h"
 #include "phys_field.h"

 using namespace std;

 int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

 PHYS_FIELD *F= new PHYS_FIELD();

 return 0;

 }
```

Comment: Reduce the size of your code to just the problematic part.

Comment: This is a guess, so I'm not writing it as an answer, but you may want to get rid of the instance field in PHYS_FIELD - it may be "shadowing" the field from DIM. (I don't know if C++ coders use "shadowing," it's a Java term.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

modify class arr1 and add a constructor that accepts zero parameters (this way we can declare arr1 G and later build it in DIM::DIM constructor

```
arr1()
{

}
```

class DIM:

```
protected:
    arr1<double> G;     //I've moved G from the constructor so that PHYS_FIELD can inherit it directly


DIM::DIM()
{
    N=10;
    G = arr1<double>(N);

    for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
        G(i)=i;

};
```

class PHYS_FIELD

remove  `arr1<double>  G;` from PHYS_FIELD header so that it doesn't hide the G inherited from DIM

```
PHYS_FIELD::PHYS_FIELD()   { //removed G(N)

    cout << " from phys_field.cpp " << endl;
    cout << N << endl;

    for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
        cout << i << " " << G(i) << endl;

};
```

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Jose, thank you! But now it is a segmentaion error. May be a hint: I passed dynamically created double array from DIM to PHYS_FIELD, it was OK. But with arr1 I have a problem.

Comment: @Maxim no problem. Maybe mark my answer as the correct one tho? That's normally what is done in this site xD